# Convert XML WebView into @Composable

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose

I would like to convert a `WebView` into a `@Composable`. I am looking for something similar to `SwiftUI's` `UIRepresentable`.

I saw there was a `@GenerateView` annotation but, 
1. that did the opposite of what I wanted(converted a `@Composable` into xml)
2. `@GenerateView` seems to have been taken away(I am using `Dev05`).

Comment: IIRC, this sort of integration is not ready yet.

Answer (score 1):

I think that feature is not supported yet. But you can interop traditional views with jetpack compose.

```kotlin
@Composable
fun Browser(list: List<String>) {
    Column(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) { item ->
        AndroidView(
                modifier = Modifier.fillParentMaxWidth().height(50.dp),
                viewBlock = { context ->
                    WebView(context).apply {
                        layoutParams = ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
                                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                        )
                    }
                })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should be using the WebComponent @Composable. It's also a great example to see how it wraps an existing view and converts it into a Composable.

Source - https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/androidx-compose-release/ui/ui-android-view/src/main/java/androidx/ui/androidview/WebComponent.kt

Comment: This isn't showing up for me. Have you tried this yourself?